# Get all tableau workbooks from server

Tags: javascript, angular, tableau-api

I have tableau server where multiple workbooks are published.
My requirement is to create dropdown list with all workbooks name with their url. So that if I select any value from ddl then the corresponding workbook should be loaded. I am able to display individual workbooks with hardcoded values in ddl.
So is it possible to get all workbooks from Tableau server?

I am very new to tableau.If there is any javascript API do let me know.
Referred link: [Javascript tableau API](https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/js_api/en-us/JavaScriptAPI/js_api_ref.htm)

Tried : http://myTableauServer/workbooks.xml but it is giving error."Page could not be loaded"

Code:

```
displayWorkbook(): void {
        let placeholderDiv = document.getElementById("tableauViz");
        let positionInfo = placeholderDiv.getBoundingClientRect();
        let getUrl = this.workbookType.find(x => x.name.trim() === this.selectedWorkeBook.trim());
        if (getUrl) {
            let url = getUrl.value;
            let options = {
                width: positionInfo.width,
                height: positionInfo.height,
                hideTabs: true,
                hideToolbar: true,
                onFirstInteractive: function () {
                    var dash =  this.tableauViz.getWorkbook().getActiveSheet();//gives only worksheet under the selected url
                    if(dash.getSheetType() === 'dashboard') {
                        var sheets = dash.getWorksheets();
                        for(var j=0; j<sheets.length; j++) {
                            this.SheetNameList.push({name : sheets.getName(),value:sheets.getUrl()});                          
                        }
                      }
            }
                }
            };
            if (this.tableauViz) { // If a viz object exists, delete it.
                this.tableauViz.dispose();
            }
            this.tableauViz = new tableau.Viz(placeholderDiv, url, options);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the Tableau Server REST API
https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/help.htm#REST/rest_api.htm

Which is easier to use via the following Python library
https://github.com/tableau/server-client-python

Comment: Thanks for reply!I will try API.